# Unable to push to Azure container registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

While trying to push new containers to the Azure container registry, I get the following errors.

```
Successfully built b5f5a0e4c64b

Successfully tagged dekkiotest1.azurecr.io:5000/c4module:0.0.1-amd64

The push refers to repository [dekkiotest1.azurecr.io:5000/c4module]

Get https://dekkiotest1.azurecr.io:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I have verified that this only occurs for new images I'm trying to push. I can update existing images alright. I have verified that the registry has memory available.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the process for pushing images to Azure registry?

Comment: Could you try to push the image with the tag `dekkiotest1.azurecr.io/c4module:0.0.1-amd64`?

Answer (score 1):

@Charles Xu,
Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, removing the port number fixed my error.

For the benefit of others, when you create a project using Visual studio code, it defaults to localhost:5000 as the registry to store the container. If you are using a MSFT container, remember to remove the port number.